# Encryptor/Decryptor using logic gates (XOR, NEG/NOT, NAND)

Tags: algorithm, encryption, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I'm working on a project in Verilog that will encrypt a 20-bit number and decrypt it back using XOR, NOT, and NAND gates.

For encryption,

1. input `XOR` `xorEncDec` (predefined operand for XOR)
2. `NOT` input (also 1's comp)
3. input `NAND` `nandEncDec` (predefined operand for NAND)

I have a problem with my decryptor. Numbers are in hex. Here is a sample output of my program:
[image]

The current logic I have right now (which is faulty) for decryption is

1. input `NAND` 2's comp of `nandEncDec`
2. `NOT` 2's comp of input
3. input `XOR` 2's comp of `xorEncDec`

I feel that I'm already close to the answer because the output in each decryption stage *seems* to be the negative representation. Can you help me fix my decryption algorithm? I'm not really looking for an answer in Verilog code, even the algorithm or the correct gates will do.

Comment: `I feel that I'm already close to the answer` - to what question? (You deleted quite a bit.)

Comment: I deleted the Verilog code because I think it is irrelevant to the question. The answer I'm referring to is the correct decryptor.

Comment: Again: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAND is an irriversible operation:

```
a b (a NAND b)
0 0 1
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0
```

If `b` is 0 and you know that the result of `(a NAND b)` is 1, you cannot know whether `a` is 0 or 1. Hence, your encryption algorithm is flawed, and it is impossible to decrypt its output.

(You presumably know the following, but I feel compelled to say it anyway: making your own crypto algorithm is a fun exercise, but *NEVER EVER* use your own crypto for anything serious; it *WILL* be broken. This applies to everyone except professional cryptographers, and even they must submit their algorithms for thorough public review before anyone would dream of using them.)

Comment: This is actually a machine problem/project under our Verilog course. :( It's my first time doing a cryptography program. Thanks for the information though! If it isn't too much, can I ask for a link regarding reversible/irreversible Boolean operations? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind the link, by merely understanding the expression's truth table I now understand what you're trying to say. I have tried using a `XNOR` gate (which is **reversible**) in replacement of `NAND`, and the number was decrypted successfully!

Comment: @ellekaie: Great! (And bonus points for actually trying to understand _why_ this happens ;-) ) As an exercise if you want to, there are 16 different ways of making a function from two bits to one (since there are 16 different ways to fill out one column in a truth table with 4 rows). While only some of them have common names like AND, OR, XOR, NAND, and NOR, all of them are valid ways of making a function and might be useful in various settings. How many of them are reversible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in trouble because it is impossible to invert a NAND gate without additional side information.

The problem is that `1 ~& 0` is the same as `0 ~& 0` so there is no way to distinguish the input 0 from the input 1.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to decrypt an irreversible operation such as NAND, given the condition that a *clue* will be generated after NAND encryption. But this of course, I believe, isn't done because it's counterintuitive to what encryption does -- security.

Anyhow, background first. NAND is a reversible operation due to inputs `0 & 0` and `1 & 0`. Both will output `1` after you NAND the inputs. Once you 'decrypt' it, given `1 & 0`, there could be no way of telling if the previous encrypted bit was `0` or `1`... unless you generated a *marker* after the NAND encryption.

To implement the marker, I used two arrays -- Array A for `0 & 0`, and Array B for `1 & 0`. The arrays are instantiated to full `0`'s (or `1`'s, if you prefer). For example, if bit 4 of each input are `0 & 0`, bit 4 of Array A will be set to `1` (or `0`, if you set it to all `1`'s).

The marker arrays are used then for decryption.

Here's a proof of my program to show the algorithm works.

[image]